# PHP - Allow client to send a message to a TLS server

Tags: php

I'm trying to understand how we can use Php socket to let our client send messages to our Node.js server using TLS...

My problem is that i don't know how that is done in Php. Can someone please show me how that can be done in php and explain the steps please???

I have tried to search on many website to gain understanding about it. To connect to TCP server in Php we can do such:

```
// IPv4
 $sock = @socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
 // IPv6
 $sock = @socket_create(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);

 $sock->connect($address);

// now we can send to the server using socket_write
```

How can the same be done with TLS instead of TCP in PHP???

I'm not looking for help with the Node.js server, just php..

Comment: If it's a NodeJS server shouldn't you be making a HTTP request to it rather than a raw TCP connection?

Comment: i'm not interested in http queries. The NodeJS server is used as real time communication.. i just want to understand how to use TLS in php.. same way i did with TCP

Comment: TLS is not an alternative to TCP, it's a security protocol. And if you're not interested in HTTP then what does it matter that it's NodeJS? Node only responds to HTTP requests. What kind of service are you trying to connect to? What port? Does it require TLS over the top?